# Every point of the set of all uncountable limit points is a limit point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A friend told me me about this problem and although maybe it is easy, I don't know how to proceed. I tried to proceed by contradiction but didn't find anything useful. I appreiate your help.

> Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb R^k$ and let $X$ be the set of all points $x$ such that every neighborhood around $x$ contains uncountably many points of $A.$ Prove that $X$ contains no isolated points.

I should add that for me a neighborhood around $x$ is the set of all points $y$ such that $\|x-y\|<\epsilon$ for some positive real number $\epsilon.$

Comment: You should choose an answer as the best. In this case, I think Brian's answer is better than mine because his method has more implications and generalizations than mine (for instance, my method cannot be applied to metric spaces in which closed ball are not always compact, e.g. $\mathbb Q$ with the usual metric, however, Brian's method can be applied to any separable metric space).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that $\Bbb R^k$ has a countable base $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. (For instance, we can take $\mathscr{B}$ to be the set of all products of the form $\prod_{i=1}^k(p_i,q_i)$, where $p_i,q_i\in\Bbb Q$ and $p_i<q_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$.)

Now suppose that $x$ is an isolated point of $X$; then $x$ has an open nbhd $U$ such that $U\cap X=\{x\}$. Let $y\in U\setminus\{x\}$; then $y\notin X$, so $y$ has an open nbhd $U_y$ such that $A\cap U_y$ is countable. $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for the topology on $\Bbb R^k$, so there is an $n(y)\in\Bbb N$ such that $y\in B_{n(y)}\subseteq U_y$. In short, for each $y\in U\setminus\{x\}$ there is an $n(y)\in\Bbb N$ such that $y\in B_{n(y)}$, and $A\cap B_{n(y)}$ is countable.

Let $M=\big\{n(y):y\in U\setminus\{x\}\big\}$, and note that $B_m\cap A$ is countable for each $m\in M$. Let $V=\bigcup_{m\in M}B_m$; $M$ is clearly countable, and

$$A\cap V=A\cap\bigcup_{m\in M}B_m=\bigcup_{m\in M}(A\cap B_m)$$

is therefore the union of countably many countable sets and hence itself countable. But $A\cap U$ is uncountable (since $U$ is an open nbhd of $x$), so $A\cap(U\setminus\{x\})$ is uncountable, and the construction of $V$ ensures that $U\setminus\{x\}\subseteq V$, so $A\cap V$ is uncountable. This contradiction shows that $x$ cannot be isolated in $X$ after all.

The basic idea is very simple, though it may have got lost in the technical details. If $x$ is isolated in $X$, it has an open nbhd $U$ that contains no other point of $X$. This means that each point of $U$ except $x$ itself has an open nbhd (and hence a basic open nbhd) containing only countably many points of $A$. There are only countably many basic open sets altogether, so the union of these basic open nbhds of points of $U\setminus\{X\}$ still contains only countably many points of $A$. But that union is all of $U$ except possibly the point $x$ itself, so $U$ contains only countably many points of $A$, contradicting the choice of $x$ as an element of $X$.

Comment: I should have said this on november 27, but thank you!.

Comment: @Gero: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in\mathbb R^k$ be such that $\exists r>0$ such that the open ball $B_r(x)$ intersects $X$ in at most its center $x.$ Then for each $y\in B_r(x)-\{x\}$ there is some $\varepsilon(y)>0$ such that $B_{\varepsilon(y)}(y)\cap A$ is at most countable. Then $\{B_{r/2^2}(x)\}\bigcup\{B_{\varepsilon(y)}(y)\}_{0<\|y-x\|\leqslant r/2}$ is an open cover of the closed ball $\overline{B_{r/2}(x)}.$ Since every closed ball is compact in $\mathbb R^k,$ then $(B_{r/2}(x)-B_{r/2^2}(x))\cap A$ is at most countable. Applying the same process again, we conclude that $(B_{r/2^2}(x)-B_{r/2^3}(x))\cap A$ is at most countable and hence $(B_{r/2}(x)-B_{r/2^3}(x))\cap A$ is at most countable. Thus if we keep applying this process we conclude that $(B_{r/2}(x)-B_{r/2^n}(x))\cap A$ is at most countable for all integers $n\geqslant2.$ Therefore $(B_{r/2}(x)-\{x\})\cap A$ is at most countable, which implies that $x\notin X.$ Hence $X$ contains no isolated points.

**Note.** A closed set with no isolated points is called [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set).

**Edit:** I made a mistake in my original answer by assuming that the collection $\{B_{\varepsilon(y)}(y)\}_{0<\|y-x\|\leqslant r/2}$ is an open cover of the closed ball $\overline{B_{r/2}(x)}$ so I hope my edited answer has no flaws.

Comment: Brian M, Scott's proof uses the fact that the space is second-countable. Your  proof uses the fact that the space is first-countable and locally compact.

Comment: I should have said this on november 27, but thank you!.